# Add a line below each line matching a pattern only if not already present

Tags: text-processing, sed

Can `sed` add a new line below a specific content, if the input content exist then leave it ?

Current content of the file `ssss`

```
Hostname example.com
Os version rhel5.6
apache 4.2

Hostname example2.com
Os version rhel5.6
```

Desired content of the file `ssss`

```
Hostname example.com
Os version rhel5.6
apache 4.2

Hostname example2.com
Os version rhel5.6
apache 4.2
```

I am able to add the content with the below command

`sed -i '/Os version rhel5.6/a apache 4.2' ssss`

**My Question**

I want to add a line below a specified content if the content exist on the file then leave it. If the content doesn't exist then add it.

Comment: This is [answered on the vi/Vim stack exchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4847/4676), or very very close.  You can likely adapt what you need out of that answer.

Comment: @Wildcard - not quite... that one is about a single line... this one has multiple lines matching a pattern and the requirement is to append the line after each match (if not there already) not at end of file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `perl` expression will do the trick,

```
perl -i -ne 'next if /apache 4.2/;s+Os version rhel5.6+Os version rhel5.6\napache 4.2+; print' ssss
```

**Explanation**

- `next if /apache 4.2/` skips any lines matching `apache 4.2`.
- `s+Os version rhel5.6+Os version rhel5.6\napache 4.2+; print` search `Os version rhel5.6` and replaces line with same with appending `apache 4.2` at newline.

**Test with your input file**

```
$ cat ssss
Hostname example.com
Os version rhel5.6
apache 4.2

Hostname example2.com
Os version rhel5.6

$ perl -ne 'next if /apache 4.2/;s+Os version rhel5.6+Os version rhel5.6\napache 4.2+; print' ssss
Hostname example.com
Os version rhel5.6
apache 4.2

Hostname example2.com
Os version rhel5.6
apache 4.2
```

Comment: your answer works well, but willing to run this in a bash script.

Comment: @Mongrel you can put perl one-liner in your bash script. It will certainly work.

Comment: The `sed` solution will delete other occurrences of `apache 2.4` too, not just the ones following `/^Os /`... It works in this case though.

Comment: @Kusalananda ohh, yeah. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed '/Os version rhel5\.6/{
a\
apache 4.2
$!{
n
/^apache 4\.2$/d
}
}' infile
```

This appends `apache 4.2` unconditionally to all lines matching `Os version rhel5.6` then (if not on the last line) it pulls in the next line via `n` (printing the pattern space) and if the new pattern space content matches `apache 4.2`  it deletes it. Adjust the regex if needed to include leading/trailing spaces e.g. `/^[[:blank:]]*apache 4\.2[[:blank:]]*$/d`

Comment: `sed -e '/Os version rhel5\.6/{a\apache 4.2' -e '$!{n;/^apache 4\.2$/d}}'` if you prefer a gnu sed one liner...

Comment: Notice that `n` does *very* different things in GNU and BSD `sed`.  In BSD `sed` it's the same as `p` unless `-n` is used (in which case it's a no-op).

Comment: I was wrong about the no-op (it does replace the pattern space), but also "Write the pattern space to the standard output if the default output has not been suppressed".

Comment: In the GNU manual it just says "Read the next line of input into the pattern space". Nothing about printing.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. I was taking the manual for what it said (and I can't access the `info` docs on my BSD system).  I'm more used to BSD `sed` (and BSD tools in general) so it was a case of not tracking down the correct documentation.

Comment: @Kusalananda - no problem. You can always consult the [online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands) (it's the _html_ version of the `info` page).

Comment: Both were great solution, but the solution which is used in my script was he above one. thanks you.